# Trouble appending value in React Native

Tags: string, react-native, variables, append

I have some code in React Native as follows, as can be seen I am calling a routine within the "componentDidMount" that is intended to load some previously saved variables from 'storage':

```
export default class Cast extends Component {
state = {
  admin: false,
  isPublishing: false,
  userComment: "",
  hasPermission: false,
  paused: true,
  _email: false,
  _name: false,
  _pword: false,
  _play_ID: false,
  _streamkey: false,
  _playurl: "",
  _streamurl: "",
  };


getKey = async() => {
  try {
    var value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('email');
    this.setState({ _email: value });
    value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('playkey');
    this.setState({ _play_ID: value });
    const playurl = "https://stream.mux.com/" + value + ".m3u8"
    this.setState({ _playurl: playurl });
    value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('castkey');
    this.setState({ _streamkey: value });
    const streamurl = "rtmp://global-live.mux.com:5222/app/" + value
    this.setState({ _streamurl: streamurl });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error retrieving data" + error);
  }
}

componentDidMount(){
  this.getKey();
}

renderCameraView = () => {

  return (
    <NodeCameraView
      style={styles.nodeCameraView}
      /* eslint-disable */
      ref={vb => {
        this.vb = vb;
      }}
      /* eslint-enable */
      outputUrl = {this.state._streamurl}
      camera={settings.camera}
      audio={settings.audio}
      video={settings.video}
      autopreview
    />
  );
};

renderPlayerView = () => {

const { paused } = this.state;
const source = {
  uri: _playurl  //SEEMS TO ACCEPT THIS VARIABLE WITHOUT CURLY BRACKETS OR 'THIS.STATE.'...NOT SURE WHY...? 
};
  return (
    <Video
      source={source} // Can be a URL or a local file.
      /* eslint-disable */
      ref={ref => {
        this.player = ref;
      }} // Store reference
      /* eslint-enable */
      onBuffer={this.onBuffer} // Callback when remote video is buffering
      onError={this.onError} // Callback when video cannot be loaded
      style={styles.nodePlayerView}
      fullscreen={false}
      resizeMode="cover"
      paused={paused}
    />
  );
};


//...
```

The issue I am having is for some reason it is impossible to append the value of '_streamkey' to a string.  Within the 'renderCamerView' function I am attempting to set the value of 'outputUrl' without success.  This function is called upon a button press.  I have been struggling with this for quite some time.  As can be seen in my code post as currently written I am receiving a "JSX value should be either an expression or a quoted JSX text." error.  However if I try something like:

```
outputUrl="rtmp://global-live.mux.com:5222/app/" + this.state._streamkey
```

That throws an "unexpected token" error that seems to indicate the "+" is bad syntax.  Any suggestions on how to solve this are GREATLY appreciated, as mentioned this has been driving me crazy.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `_streamkey` for concatenating `_streamurl` we could use `value` directly. You cannot use the value of `_streamkey` in the same render cycle in which you set it since `setState` is asyncronous. If we log `this.state._streamkey` in `getKey` right after you have set it, you won't get the newly set value.

You can find this in the official react-native documentation.

> setState() enqueues changes to the component state and tells React that this component and its children need to be re-rendered with the updated state. This is the primary method you use to update the user interface in response to event handlers and server responses.

> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state right after calling setState() a potential pitfall.

Try the following.

```js
getKey = async() => {
  try {
    var value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('email');
    this.setState({ _email: value });
    value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('castkey');
    this.setState({ _streamkey: value });
    const streamurl = "rtmp://global-live.mux.com:5222/app/" + value
    this.setState({ _streamurl: streamurl });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error retrieving data" + error);
  }
}
```

Your access to the state property `_streamurl` is incorrect and you need to use curly brackets when you pass a component prop. Try the following code.

```js
render() {
    return <NodeCameraView
      style={styles.nodeCameraView}
      /* eslint-disable */
      ref={vb => {
        this.vb = vb;
      }}
      /* eslint-enable */
      outputUrl={this.state._streamurl}  
      camera={settings.camera}
      audio={settings.audio}
      video={settings.video}
      autopreview
    />
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response.  Please refer to my edited code above.  I implemented the suggestions you made and it seems to be operative, I have to test some more but at least no errors are being thrown.  In my edited code above I also added the function "renderPlayerView", which was similar as a 'uri' needed to be supplied, however in that case I simply added the variable directly, without any usage of curly brackets...again I need to test further however there are no errors being thrown...any idea what is the difference in these 2 functions as far as accepting those variable strings?

Comment: Do you mean the usage of `resizeMode="cover"`? Why no brackets are needed here?

Comment: No, in "renderCameraView" I have "outputUrl = {this.state._streamurl}"...again it is not throwing an error.  However in "renderPlayerView" I have "uri: _playurl" which is also not throwing an error...however when I originally attempting to use "{this.state._playurl}" with the curly brackets and 'this.state.' prefix it didn't like that...not sure why the difference...?

Comment: Ooh I see. That is indeed different. `const source = {uri: _playurl };` actually creates a new object with the property `uri` which you assign `_playurl`. This has nothing to do with react-native. This is plain JS. However, when you pass prop like `outputUrl = {this.state._streamurl}`, then you are using a JSX component which is a react-native construction and here the syntax is that for everything other than string you need curly braces.

Comment: The syntax `this.state` is needed when you access a state in a class component. If you are using a functional component, then this becomes more handy. We use `const [playurl, setPlayurl] = useState()` in a functional component and here we cann just use `playurl` as every other variable.

Comment: However, in class components you could use destructuring as follows: `const {_streamurl} = this.state` in the render method.

Comment: OK thanks for the information...I also didn't realize a function within a class component, as I have posted above...could utilize 'useState'...I thought that was only allowed in 'pure' functions (outside of class components).  The way React Native handles variables is a completely confusing mess for me...hopefully as I test this code further I will not encounter any other issues such as this again.  Your help is GREATLY appreciated!  Thanks again.

Comment: No, this is not what I mean. You can't use `useState` in class components of course. I meant that IF you use a functional component, then you can use it this way.

Comment: OK thanks for the clarification and all the other information, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to tweak your syntax a bit to do string concatenation in your react component:

```
outputUrl={"rtmp://global-live.mux.com:5222/app/" + this.state._streamkey}
```

or use string interpolation:

```
outputUrl={`rtmp://global-live.mux.com:5222/app/${this.state._streamkey}`}
```

Does that help?

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your time to respond very much, I attempted both strings you offered however still had errors thrown.  I don't know what the cause, I had some better luck with Mr. Scholz's suggestion below.  Once again your reply is appreciated.